# How to update Images with kustomize edit from GitHub Actions in a multi-job scenario

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-kubernetes-engine, kustomize

I have two applications (identity and API) in a single repository. I have set up in a CI/CD pipeline to deploy them to kubernetes; the images are building fine.

How can I structure the `kustomization.yaml` file to deploy the image edits without updating the images with wrong data? I noticed the two apps are pointing to the same image.

```yaml
jobs:          
  identity-job:
   ...                                                                        
   ./kustomize edit set image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IDSIMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA
   ./kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -

   api-job:
   ...                                                                        
   ./kustomize edit set image gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/IMAGE:TAG=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$APIIMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA
   ./kustomize build . | kubectl apply -f -
```

Comment: So the manifests are all referencing the same image? But you are build two separate images? Why not also store two separate images in the manifests so you can `kustomize edit set image` both of them separately

Answer (score 0):

Should you need to update the <kbd>kustomization.yaml</kbd> file? What about to directly [edit the deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment), like:

```
kubectl -n <namespace-name> set image <deployment-name> <pod-name>=<container-image-name>
```

as example

```
kubectl -n identity-job set image deployment/identity-job job=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IDSIMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA
```

Comment: kubectl -n namespade set image deployment/$DEPLOYMENT_NAME $DEPLOYMENT_NAME=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$IMAGE:$GITHUB_SHA